# Regex limit the number of letters total in the entire string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this expression which is almost what I need:

```
/(?=^.{5,12}$)(^[a-zA-Z\u0590-\u05fe]{0,4}[0-9]{3,8}[a-zA-Z\u0590-\u05fe]{0,4}$)/
```

except, I need to only allow 4 letters total (4 in the beginning and 0 in the end,3 and 1, 2 and 2, 0 and 4, etc...)

allowed inputs:
11abcd11
1abcdefg123
abcd1234

unallowed inputs:
1abcd11
abcd123
1abcd12

is there a way to achieve this? thanks!

Comment: please provide some sample input and expected output

Comment: Should it be zero, one, two, three or four, or exactly 4?

Comment: just wrap everything in parentheiss and put {4} after it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure there are exactly four letters in the string, you can use

```
^(?=.{5,12}$)(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z\u0590-\u05fe]*[a-zA-Z\u0590-\u05fe]){4}[^a-zA-Z\u0590-\u05fe]*$)[a-zA-Z\u0590-\u05fe]{0,4}[0-9]{3,8}[a-zA-Z\u0590-\u05fe]{0,4}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2lC7Ck/1)

The `(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z\u0590-\u05fe]*[a-zA-Z\u0590-\u05fe]){4}[^a-zA-Z\u0590-\u05fe]*$)` positive lookahead makes sure there are four sequences of any zero or more "non-letters" followed with a "letter" and then there are zero or more "non-letters" till the end of string.

If you can target ECMAScript 2018+ compliant engines you can use a Unicode-aware version:

```js
/^(?=.{5,12}$)(?=(?:\P{L}*\p{L}){4}\P{L}*$)\p{L}{0,4}[0-9]{3,8}\p{L}{0,4}$/u
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2lC7Ck/2), where `\p{L}` matches letters. You may also replace it with `\p{Alphabetic}` which also matches letters that are Roman numbers.